# Cell equal value of active cell which is a drop down

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a cell which i declared as active cell using developers tool in excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("C1").Value = ActiveCell.Value

End Sub
```

this cell is equals to the value of a drop down cell i created from data validation.

My Problem is cell C1 is not changing when i select a new value from the drop down

Comment: You can't "Declare an ActiveCell". Most of the time, the `ActiveCell` is the cell you last clicked on. You can also use code to `Activate` a particular cell and such make it the `ActiveCell` but that status will be lost the moment the user clicks elsewhere. In your code `Target` is the `ActiveCell` Therefore `Range("C1").Value = Target.Value` should be what you want. Actually, your code should do that even though the syntax strikes me as odd. But it responds to the *Selection_Change*, not the *Change* event.

Comment: If you were to place your code in a procedure declared as `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`, C1 would assume the value of whichever cell you change. As it is, C1 should assume the value of whatever cell you click on. Normally the event procedure would be limited in its action, like `If Target.Address = Range("A10").Address Then Range("C1").Value = Target.Value` or `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A:A") Is Nothing Then Range("C1").Value = Target.Value`

Comment: Cell C1 is working correctly when i click and cell, the C1 get the value of that cell. But my issue is that, i have created drop down from Data Validation in specific cells.

At first, when i click that cell , assume B1, C1 get the correct value of that cell, but when i select a new value from B1's drop down, C1 dose not change , it keeps that initial value.

Is there a ways to make C1, change when i select a new value from B1's Drop Down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. When B1 is changed C1 is assigned the value of B1. It doesn't matter how the change was carried out, from the keyboard or by selection from a drop-down.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("B1").Address Then
        ' prevent the coming change from causing a call of this procedure
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(1, "C").Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ' Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Range("C1").Formula= "=" & ActiveCell.Address

End Sub'

Comment: Your procedure will refresh the value of C1 every time you click anywhere on the sheet but not when B1 is modified. My procedure will change the value of C1 only when a change is made in B1. The point is that your procedure responds to the click and mine responds to the change. Yours doesn't meet the requirement you maid out in your question.

Comment: Am Sorry, maybe i was bad explaining.
i would like to thank you alot, as i will also be using you code elsewhere.
Many Thanks